# Check if a scheduled task is running using vbscript

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

Is it possible to determine if a scheduled task is running on a local or remote machine using vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

There's a WMI class called [Win32_ScheduledJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has some status fields that might be useful. Especially the `ElapsedTime` field looks like it might be what you're looking for, assuming that it gets reset when the task stops.
[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) some sample code for looking at the statuses. Just set `strComputer` to the name of the computer you want to look at (`.` means the local computer).

Otherwise, if that doesn't work, you might be able to just look at the `Schedlgu.txt` file in the `Windows` directory and see if it's started but not yet stopped.

Comment: Unfortunately:  _"The Win32_ScheduledJob WMI class represents a job created with the AT command. The Win32_ScheduledJob class does not represent a job created with the Scheduled Task Wizard from the Control Panel. You cannot change a task created by WMI in the Scheduled Tasks UI"_

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get this information with the command-line command `schtasks /query`... but you'd probably have to grep the output to find only the jobs with a status of "Running".

Details on usage can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_query).